# I'm getting the below error while installing MySQL Python packages in anaconda environment

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, conda

```bash
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - mysql-connector-python -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
  - mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for. When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package vs2015_runtime conflicts for:
mysql-connector-c -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
pymysql -> cryptography -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
python=3.8 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
python=3.8 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
mysql-connector-python -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
mysql-connector-python -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
mysql-python -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
mysql-connector-c -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']

Package six conflicts for:
mysql-connector-python -> protobuf[version='>=3.0.0'] -> six
pymysql -> cryptography -> six[version='>=1.4.1']

Package vc conflicts for:
mysql-python -> vc=9
mysql-python -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']

Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1f,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
mysql-connector-python -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1f,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
pymysql -> cryptography -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1f,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a']

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
pymysql -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates

Package vs2008_runtime conflicts for:
pymysql -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> vs2008_runtime
mysql-connector-c -> vc=9 -> vs2008_runtime[version='>=9.0.30729.1,<10.0a0']
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> vs2008_runtime[version='>=9.0.30729.1,<10.0a0']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
mysql-connector-python -> protobuf[version='>=3.0.0'] -> setuptools
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools

Package mysql-connector-c conflicts for:
mysql-connector-python -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0']
mysql-python -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0']
```

Comment: please add the commands that were used that led to this error.

Comment: Anaconda Navigator Screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeXKV.jpg I Entered MYSQL in the search option and I had checked all the tick boxes, clicked installed button. Then I got the error.

Comment: It seems like you need to do more research about interfacing with mysql through Python. Figure out which package(s) you actually need first, rather than trying to install every package that includes "mysql" in the package name.

Answer (score 0):

The package `mysql-python` is only for Python 2.7 and you don't need both that and `mysql-connector-python`. Just install the latter.